# How to print Jacoco code coverage with Azure Devops for a Android Project?

Tags: android, azure-devops, jacoco

We use Azure DevOps to build our Android App and distribute it. The code is written in Kotlin. We are using the Gradle@2 script as defined in the following document.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/gradle-v2?view=azure-pipelines

This document says that we could use the Jacoco code coverage tool. My question is "codeCoverageClassFilesDirectories" parameter is the path to my Kotlin files for which I need code coverage?

Do we need any change in Android Studio to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The input '**`codeCoverageClassFilesDirectories`**' on [**Gradle task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/gradle-v2?view=azure-pipelines) is used to specify the directories which contain the source files (class files and archive files) you need code coverage.

You also can use the input '**`codeCoverageClassFilter`**' to specify some pattens to filter (include or exclude) the detailed classes from code coverage.

Normally, you do not need extra changes in Android Studio for the **Gradle task**. You just need to follow the guide on the docs of this task to configure in your pipeline and make the task can successfully run the build and test. Also the code coverage tool you select is available.